# Always show all items on start context menu

Tags: windows-10, start-menu, context-menu

I am not sure why windows 10 shows more options on start menu icons, while there is only 5 options at all.

For example:

[image]

Is there any way to disable this? So, I would like to see all items under context menu.

Comment: Doubtful.  I think it's more a case of MS trying to hide complexity from users who would just be confused or get themselves in trouble with those menu options than it is about conserving space on the context menu.

Comment: You would have to replace the shell with something other then Explorer to change the behavior of the context menu.